# Can a Grappler move freely without moving the grappled creature and breaking the grapple condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, grapple, conditions, reach

My interpretation of the rules is that the grappler can move freely as long as the grappled stays on the grappler reach. But I want to be sure.

#### What happens in the situation where reach is greater than attack range?

- A is an Otyugh and B is a humanoid.  Keep in mind that the Otyugh's
  tentacle reach is 10 ft. and the bite attack range is 5 ft.

  - A is grappling B. B is 10 ft. away from A. A moves closer to B to make a bite attack.
  - A is grappling B. They're adjacent to each other. A moves 5 ft. away from B  to put himself out of B reach.
  - A is grappling B. Both are at the edge of a chasm. A circles around B to be able to shove B into the chasm.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes,** a grappler can move within their reach without ending the grapple.

**Grappled condition** (PHB, p. 290):

> The [grappled] condition also ends if an effect removes the
>   grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect ...

**Moving a Grappled Creature** (PHB, p. 195):

> When you move, you **can** drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

Dragging/carrying the grappled creature is optional (the rule says *can*), and the grapple doesn't end unless the move puts the grappled creature out of reach.

All of the situations are fine: the otyugh (A) can move as described in each case. Note that its speed will be halved, however, even if it isn't moving the grappled creature.

Comment: I agree that the grappler may choose to drag or not to drag the grappled creature when moving, however, I'm not sure that I agree speed is halved *regardless.*  To me, the quoted passage reads that speed is halved **if** you're dragging the grappled creature with you (and provided that creature is not two or more sizes smaller.)

Comment: Steve even moving around them requires you fight against them, so you are dragging them around to maintain your grip.  Have you ever held onto a unwilling person and turned around them?  Say your kid has sticky stuff on their hands, and you grab them before they can spread it throgh out your home, but you need to grab the wipes which are on the counter on the other side of them?  Yeah, movement being only halved is the game being kind. :)

Comment: I don't think the speed reduction is conditional (note the absence of an "if you do" after the "but" in the rule). If you think it's really contentious, I can remove the last sentence and open a new question on that specific issue.

Comment: I find this to be accurate. Another way to look at it is if you're maintaining the grapple and moving, you're still 'moving a grappled creature', they're just ending up in the same location.

Comment: If the grappled creature doesn't move you aren't moving it.  The speed reduction is clearly under the section for moving a grappled creature.  It might not make sense that you can still move full speed (for humans), but the rules do not support halving the Otyugh's speed in this case.  I can't +1 the answer with that last sentence in it.

Comment: @NickBrown See my prior comment on the non-conditional wording of the rule.

Comment: But its presence in a subsection on moving a grappled creature makes it conditional.  This is exactly like the rule against casting additional non-cantrip spells when you cast a bonus action which is only under casting spells as a bonus action and has no effect on casting spells in general.

Comment: Steve and Nick (and @DungeonSecurity) are quite simply correct; there is no way the structure of that sentence can justify applying the movement reduction if you don't move the creature. “You can ... but ...” **is** a conditional structure in the English language. Based only on what’s quoted in the answer, your conclusion is simply and objectively wrong. You either need other evidence for that conclusion, or it should be removed as, in the absence of other evidence, it is inaccurate.